# why formatter doesn't work in fragment xml?

Tags: javascript, fragment, formatter, sapui5

there is a formatter function in my other lib and my aim is to use this function. Here my Formatter.js :

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
"use strict";
    var Formatter = {
        showAsDate : function(str){...}
    };

    return Formatter;
 });
```

And in my fragment I'm using it like below :

```
<Text text="{
    path: 'jsonModel>/date',
    formatter : '.Formatter.showAsDate'
    }" />
```

and I call Formatter.js in my controller like below:

```
sap.ui.define(["libpath/Formatter"], function (Formatter){
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("controller.myController", {

        Formatter : Formatter,

        //I add my fragment to myView with this method
        //and I am calling this method in onInit.
        _showFormFragment : function (sFragmentName) {
            var oPage = this.getView().byId("page");
            oPage.removeAllContent();
            oPage.insertContent(this._getFormFragment(sFragmentName));
        }
    });

});
```

I am using [openui5beta library](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/99ac68a5b1c3416ab5c84c99fefa250d.html).And I coded my view and controllers according to the [walkthrough sapmle](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.35/code). And you can see similar usage in [InvoiceList.controller.js](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.35/code/webapp%252Fcontroller%252FInvoiceList.controller.js), [InvoiceList.view.xml](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.35/code/webapp%252Fview%252FInvoiceList.view.xml), [HelloDialog.fragment.xml](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.35/code/webapp%252Fview%252FHelloDialog.fragment.xml)
. But these samples show how to reach formatter from view not from fragment.  I am able to reach Formatter.js from myView.view.xml but I can't reach it from my fragment.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you share how your fragment is invoked?
Usually when fragment is invoked you have an additional parameter to specify the JS Object context like this

```
var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("YourFragment.xml",this);
```

the above code is called in a controller so "this" would refer to controller instance and the format functions should work.

Comment: it was invoked like 'oFormFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "view." + sFragmentName);' but now I added "this" parameter to the end and it is working. Thank you so much.